# TextView setText not working with string from SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite, textview, settext

I have a programmatically created TextView inside my layout.

```
String dataname;
dataname="test name";

TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText(dataname);
```

this works as expected.

If I set the dataname from the SQL database, it doesn't work.    Here is the code snippets that pulls the data.

The table class declaration includes:

```
public class TblTest {
     private int     _id;
     private String  _name;
```

The function that returns the field

```
public String get_name() {
    return this._name;
}
```

The modified call that "should" put the data in the TextView

```
String dataname;

String dataname=test.get_name();

Log.i("TESTLOG","dataname="+dataname);

TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText(dataname);
```

The TESTLOG shows the proper name from the database in the dataname variable.   The TextView shows a single pixel character it appears (hard to tell).

Not sure why this is happening.    Any suggestions?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION 09/21/15**

The database code works with an edit activity as is... including the name field.    I can setText it to an EditView like this...

```
etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
etName.setText(test.get_name());
```

The _name field is set from the database during an SQL rawQuery using the following...

```
test.set_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TEST_FLD_NAME)));
```

and the set_name function reads...

```
public void set_name(String name){
    this._name=name;
}
```

The TextView tv is added right after it is set to the RelativeLayout with...

```
        testrl.addView(tv);
```

The XML file with the main layout that is NOT programmatically added looks like this...

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.30"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llTest"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Along with the programmatically entered code...

```
LinearLayout scrolllayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llTest);
RelativeLayout testrl = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

// code above for setting TextView is here

scrolllayout.addView(testrl,tvp);
```

Keep in mind as a recap as to what seems odd:

- The database code works as written in other activities
- The Log.i shows that the dataname variable contains the proper data from the database right before the setText
- If I manually fill in the dataname, it shows up properly in the TextView tv
- It only fails when the dataname COMES from the database, even though it has the name in it (again, according to the Log.i)

Hope this helps too...

Comment: Where do you set the `_name` value?

Comment: try string.valueOf(), toString() or add a " "

Comment: Can you show you `xml` layout

Comment: How are you adding the programaticaly created textview to the screen?

Comment: Posted additional information to main question,  to answer questions asked in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else using this question for help, I figured  what it took to fix it, but not sure why it didn't work the way I had it.   The LayoutParam reads...

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

for whatever reason, it needs to be...

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Hope that helps anyone else... although I would really like to know why WRAP_CONTENT for the width didn't work.